# TList descendant with another otbject?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to impliment a TList descendant of controls + an extra object.
something like:

```
List.Add(AControl, AObject)
```

So The List will hold both `AControl, AObject`

What is the best way of doing this with Delphi 7?

Comment: Upgrade to modern delphi and use the generic list class

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know about generic list classes in "modern delphi". I'm using Delphi7 and I can't Updgrade.

Comment: You asked for the best way..... Just saying. As it is you'll have to build some class on TList that deals with heap alloc. Painful. Or perhaps use the synopse dyn array booster.

Comment: try to create a container class, like TMyContainer, and this class holds the two or more objects, in your list, add the container object, and in the container object add the two or more objects

Comment: -1 for incomplete specification. Now it has to be a descendant after two answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can store a list of records, then you can put whatever you want into the record, eg:

```
type
  PMyRecord = ^MyRecord;
  MyRecord = record
    Control: TControl;
    Object: TObject;
  end;

var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  New(Rec);
  try
    Rec.Control := AControl;
    Rec.Object := AObject;
    List.Add(Rec);
  except
    Dispose(Rec);
    Raise;
  end;
end;
```

```
var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  Rec := PMyRecord(List[SomeIndex]);
  // use Rec.Control and Rec.Object as needed...
end;
```

Don't forget to `Dispose()` an item when you remove it from the list:

```
var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  Rec := PMyRecord(List[SomeIndex]);
  List.Delete(SomeIndex);
  Dispose(Rec);
end;
```

And also when you are finished using the list, or at least when you `Clear()` it:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  for I := o to List.Count-1 do
    Dispose(PMyRecord(List[I]));
  //...
end;
```

If you derive a new class from `TList`, you can override its virtual `Notify()` method to dispose items:

```
type
  TMyList = class(TList)
  protected
    function Get(Index: Integer): PMyRecord;
    procedure Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification); override;
  public
    function Add(AControl: TControl; AObject: TObject): Integer;
    procedure Insert(Index: Integer; AControl: TControl; AObject: TObject);
    property Items[Index: Integer]: PMyRecord read Get; default;
  end;

function TMyList.Add(AControl: TControl; AObject: TObject): Integer;
var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  New(Rec);
  try
    Rec.Control := AControl;
    Rec.Object := AObject;
    Result := inherited Add(Rec);
  except
    Dispose(Rec);
    Raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyList.Insert(Index: Integer; AControl: TControl; AObject: TObject);
var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
begin
  New(Rec);
  try
    Rec.Control := AControl;
    Rec.Object := AObject;
    inherited Insert(Index, Rec);
  except
    Dispose(Rec);
    Raise;
  end;
end;

function TMyList.Get(Index: Integer): PMyRecord;
begin
  Result := PMyRecord(inherited Get(Index));
end;

procedure TMyList.Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification);
begin
  inherited;
  if Action = lnDeleted then
    Dispose(PMyRecord(Ptr));
end;
```

Comment: Or use `TObjectList` if forgetful

Comment: That would work if you create a new class instead of a record to hold the list values. Personally, I think the extra class would be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: It would be the easiest solution. For a record one would need to derive a new class and override Notify to make it convenient. Ah, I see you have demonstrated that. Better. +1

Comment: +1 for adding a type avare list class intead of just using TList.

Comment: When I compile the suggested Dispose for records I get a cast error:
shouldn't be like this?
`code
var
  Rec: PMyRecord;
  a: MyRecord;
begin
  a := List[SomeIndex];
  Rec := @a;
  List.Delete(SomeIndex);
  Dispose(Rec);
end;`

Comment: @Taochok no, because `List.Items[]` returns a pointer to a `MyRecord`, not an instance of a `MyRecord`, so `a := List[SomeIndex]` will not compile. And even if it did, `a` is a local variable on the stack, so `@a` would be the wrong address to dispose the original record, and it would be disposing stack memory and likely crash the app. What cast error are you getting? I see nothing wrong in the code I posted. Maybe you didn't copy it into your code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyContainer = class
  public
     ctnGen: TControl;
     objGen: TObject;
     constructor Create(const ctnGen: TControl; const objGen: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Contnrs;

{$R *.DFM}

{ TMyContainer }

constructor TMyContainer.Create(const ctnGen: TControl;
  const objGen: TObject);
begin
   inherited Create();
   Self.ctnGen := ctnGen;
   Self.objGen := objGen;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   lstGen: TObjectList;
begin
   lstGen := TObjectList.Create(True);
   try
      lstGen.Add(TMyContainer.Create(Self, Self));
      ShowMessage(TMyContainer(lstGen.Items[0]).objGen.ClassName);
   finally
      lstGen.Free;
   end;                                          
end;
```

TObjectList will free the TMyContainer class

Comment: Welcome to leak paradise. Perhaps a TObjectList to solve that.